# Integer gets formatted with commas when it gets fetched from a ResourceBundle

Tags: java, resourcebundle

```
year.of.birth={0} was born on {1}

If I pass 2000 or 2008 to {1} the value gets parsed as 2,000 or 2,008.
```

I don't want the commas as part of my translated string. How should I avoid this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The easy way is to pass them as Strings:

```
msg.format("year.of.birth", name,  String.valueOf(2008));
```

An alternative is to specify the number format in the message resource (but I would only do that if the format can vary between locales):

```
year.of.birth={0} was born in {1,number,####}
```

Comment: hm, why a downvote here.. +1 from me. The way MessageFormat works is - it checks the type and applies a formatter. So no way to work around that in an easier way.

Comment: Yes, correct way to use patterns with MessageFormat if you want to display it a particular way. +1

Comment: Since 2008 is apparently a year, you can also use Date instead of Integer (`{1,date,yyyy}`)